# Sincronización con SQLite y MySQL en Android Studio

Tags: mysql, android-studio, sqlite, volley

estoy tratando de realizar una aplicación en la que cada vez que se haga un cambio en la base interna o la base del servidor se vea reflejado en ambos, si el móvil se quedo si conexión, al momento de conectarse sincronizar los datos con la base externa. 
Actualmente estoy usando la Librería Volley para obtener los datos, sin embargo estos solo se obtienen al realizar un evento en primer plano de la aplicación, intente obtener los datos en segundo plano usando ConnectivityManager junto con CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE en el Manifest para que al tener conexión de red mandar la petición al servidor de los registros que no hayan sido enviados (cada registro teniendo un campo de verdadero o falso, si hay conexión se registra en la base interna con el campo en verdadero y se envían los datos al servidor).
Sin embargo leí que CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE ya está en desuso para Android 7 en adelante y no encuentro forma de hacer esto mismo, también pensaba usar SyncAdapter pero en varios foros leí que no es compatible con Volley. 
Estoy muy confundido.

Comment: firebase seria una buena opcion.. solo que es noSQL .. por otro lado lo que he hecho es poner al registro de SQLite una bandera que diha si esta sincronizado o no con el servidor, Tuve muchos probelams usando Volley al final uso okhttp3

Comment: Algo que olvidé comentar es que son datos delicados que no pueden ser expuestos ante una base en la nube como lo es FireBase

Answer (score 0):

Finalmente decidí lanzar un servicio en segundo plano al iniciar la aplicación, este servicio extiende de service y ejecuto un timer, para que cada cierto tiempo compruebe que haya conexión y en caso de haber hacer la consulta a SQLite, verificar el campo de cada registro, sino está sincronizado, hacer la petición al servidor con volley y si hubo respuesta valida por parte del servidor, se actualiza el campo en el registro de SQLite. 
Código: 
    public class ScheduledService extends Service{
      final Context context=this;
      private Timer timer = new Timer();

```
  @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            { //Consultar si hay conexión y verificar conexión a internet con un ping 
                a google.com
                /*en caso de haber, hacer consulta en SQLite, y mediante Cursor 
                 verificar que campo no ha sido sincronizado, hacer petición con 
                 volley al servidor con los datos del registro que no se ha 
                 sincronizado. */
            }
        },0,10*1000);// cada 10 segundos
```

}

Utilizar onStartCommand para cuando es matada la aplicación, revivir el servicio.